# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... libocijdbc12.so: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied

Tags: oracle, tomcat, unsatisfiedlinkerror

After updating Tomcat on the server

```
Updated     tomcat-7.0.69-11.el7_3.noarch                              @rhel-7-server-rpms
Update             7.0.76-3.el7_4.noarch                               @rhel-7-server-rpms
Updated     tomcat-admin-webapps-7.0.69-11.el7_3.noarch                @rhel-7-server-rpms
Update                           7.0.76-3.el7_4.noarch                 @rhel-7-server-rpms
Updated     tomcat-el-2.2-api-7.0.69-11.el7_3.noarch                   @rhel-7-server-rpms
Update                        7.0.76-3.el7_4.noarch                    @rhel-7-server-rpms
Updated     tomcat-jsp-2.2-api-7.0.69-11.el7_3.noarch                  @rhel-7-server-rpms
Update                         7.0.76-3.el7_4.noarch                   @rhel-7-server-rpms
Updated     tomcat-lib-7.0.69-11.el7_3.noarch                          @rhel-7-server-rpms
Update                 7.0.76-3.el7_4.noarch                           @rhel-7-server-rpms
Updated     tomcat-servlet-3.0-api-7.0.69-11.el7_3.noarch              @rhel-7-server-rpms
Update                             7.0.76-3.el7_4.noarch               @rhel-7-server-rpms
```

I get the error: **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libocijdbc12.so: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied**

The files in /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/ are readable (no execution permissions needed).

The server was working without any issues before this update (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, 
TNS_ADMIN, ORACLE_HOME are set).

A stand alone java application is working fine using the same Oracle client so the problem should be in Tomcat but I have no idea what to check.

Does anyone has some hints about what to look for?

**[edit:] Disabling Selinux everything is fine. What settings do I have to set in Selinux to fix this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `man  execstack`. And why you don't need execution  permissions?

Comment: The problem is in SELinux. With  SELinux disabled everything is working fine.

Comment: Enable sellinux and add result of this. `sestatus -b`.

Comment: Here is the result: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Pe9NUhBedMr5inWbDi2bCxE-7MhfgJf (too long to pass as comment). With the "Current mode:                   permissive" is working but I will have to fix the problem and set it back to enforcing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my problem was the Oracle Instant client 12.1.
Reinstalling the 12.1 did not solved the problem but uninstalling the 12.1 client and **installing the Instant client 12.2 did solved my problem** without changing anything in SELinux.

Hope this will help others.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing. turn on 'httpd_execmem' and 'httpd_can_network_connect_db' but you have to check what is purpose of other entries httpd*.

Comment: Turning on 'httpd_execmem' and 'httpd_can_network_connect_db' does not help.